# How can i Order the flow of execution of different promises in a correct way to get results?

Tags: javascript, promise, settimeout

Flow of the promise chain execution

[image: Flow of the promise chain execution]

```
const timeoutPromise = (interval, intervalName) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(function(){
      console.log(`Executed ${intervalName} at: ${new Date().toString()} with interval of ${interval}`);
      resolve();
    }, interval);
  });
};
let main = () => {
  console.log('Starting at:', new Date().toString());

  console.log('Completed at:', new Date().toString());
};
```

> From the above-given image, create a function that takes 2 fields as an argument:
> -   a letter (in our case, A, B, C, D)
> -   Time in milliseconds will be any distinct values provided by you
>
> Inside the function, there must be a setTimeout with the value as above-mentioned time
>
> The main function will start the execution such that the above-created function will be executed in the chronology specified above, i.e.:
> -   A & D will start together
> -   C will only start after completion of A & D
> -   B will start right after completion of A
>
> The execution must be in such a manner that:
> -   Time and message should be logged in console when program execution starts
> -   Time and message should be logged in console when program execution ends
> -   Time and letter should be logged each time the function is called

I tried all the possible ways but either function A is running twice or B is logged after the program execution ends...

Comment: Show us an example of what you tried and expected to work, and we can tell you why it didn't.

Comment: Use `Promise.all()` to wait for multiple promisses before the next step. You can use this to make C wait for A and B

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To resolve promises in a specific order, you need to chain them accordingly. Following is a breakdown of one of the ways it can be done:

1. As `A` and `D` can start immediately, we call the `timeoutPromise` function and save the returned promises in variables so we can reference them later.
2. As we need to start `B` as soon as `A` resolves, we can save a reference to the `A` promise in a variable so that we can start `B` when `A` completes.
3. We can use `Promise.all` to wait for both `A` and `D` to resolve before we start `C`. The resulting promise is again stored into a variable.
4. `Promise.all` is used to wait for `B` and `C` promises to settle to ensure that both promises have settled before we end the execution.

**Running example:**

```js
const timeoutPromise = (seconds, intervalName) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(function () {
      console.log(
        `Executed ${intervalName} at: ${new Date().toString()} with interval of ${seconds} seconds`
      );
      resolve();
    }, seconds * 1000);
  });
};

let main = () => {
  console.log('Starting at:', new Date().toString());

  const promiseA = timeoutPromise(1, 'A');
  const promiseAandD = Promise.all([promiseA, timeoutPromise(4, 'D')]);

  const promiseBThen = promiseA.then(() => timeoutPromise(1, 'B'));
  const promiseCThen = promiseAandD.then(() => timeoutPromise(1, 'C'));

  Promise.all([promiseCThen, promiseBThen]).then(
    () => {
      console.log('Completed at:', new Date().toString());
    }
  );
};

main();
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `setTimeout` is very likely not the best way to stage a sequence of promises. Here is a different approach involving an `async` function to help clarifying the execution order:

```js
// helper function to create a promise:
function prom(name,delay){
  return new Promise((res,rej)=>{
  setTimeout(()=>{
   console.log(`promise ${name}: ${delay}ms`);
   res(name)}, delay);
});
}

async function main(){
 let [d,a]=await Promise.all([prom("D",400),prom("A",200)]);
 let [c,b]=await Promise.all([prom("C",300),prom("B",100)]);
 console.log(`all done: ${[a,b,c,d].join(", ")}`)
}

main()
```

At first the promises D and A are awaited in parallel. Once they are fulfilled the promises C and B are awaited in parallel. Admittedly, the promise B could have started a tiny bit earlier as it does not depend on the fulfillment of D, but this will not really make a significant difference in the end. And, in the interest of an easy to read and understand code, I consider this solution to be adequate.

**Update**

Ok, here is another version - slightly more difficult to read - that will allow D and B to partly run in parallel (B can start after A was resolved):

```js
// helper function to create a promise:
function prom(name,delay,...args){
  console.log(`starting ${name}, using arguments: [${args.join(", ")}].`);
  return new Promise((res,rej)=>{
  setTimeout(()=>{
   console.log(`resolved ${name} after ${delay}ms`);
   res(name)}, delay);
});
}

async function main(){
 const [D,A] = [prom("D",2000),prom("A",1000)]; // define the promises D and A immediatey
 const [c,b] = await Promise.all([              // await promises C and B ...
   Promise.all([D,A]).then(args=>prom("C",2000,...args)),   // define promise C after D and A are resolved
                    A.then(args=>prom("B",2000,...args)) ]);// define promise B after A is resolved
 console.log(`All promises resolved, here is the data: ${await A}, ${b}, ${c}, ${await D}.`);
}

main()
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height:100%}
```

Don't be fooled by the `await A` and `await D` at the end of the script: As both promises are already resolved, no extra time is spent in "waiting" here. The `await` is necessary to access the returned data from the promises `a` and `d`.

Comment: D and B should be able to run concurrently since they do not depend on each other.

Answer (score -1):

In addition to Yousaf's answer, here is an attempt at generalization. Let the term "task" denote a function that returns a promise.

```js
class Task {
  constructor(task) {
    this.task = task;
    this.prereqs = [];
    this.succcnt = 0;
  }
  after(p) {
    this.prereqs.push(p);
    p.succcnt++;
  }
}
class Tasks {
  tasks = [];
  add(task) {
    var p = new Task(task);
    this.tasks.push(p);
    return p;
  }
  execute() {
    var tasks = [];
    while (tasks.length < this.tasks.length) {
      var l = tasks.length;
      this.tasks.filter(q => q.succcnt === 0).forEach(function(p) {
        tasks.unshift(p);
        for (var q of p.prereqs) q.succcnt--;
        p.succcnt = -1;
      });
      if (tasks.length === l)
        return Promise.reject("cyclic dependencies");
    }
    for (var p of tasks)
      p.task = Promise.all(p.prereqs.map(q => q.task)).then(p.task);
    return Promise.all(this.tasks.map(q => q.task));
  }
}
```

Individual tasks can be `add`ed to a `Tasks` instance and their `after` methods are called for every other task on which they depend. Then, the `execute` method of the `Tasks` instance executes them all in the necessary order (if it can find one, that is, unless there are cyclic dependencies).

```js
function makePromise(x) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    console.log(x, "starts");
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(x, "ends");
      resolve(x);
    }, 1000);
  });
}
var p = new Tasks();
var A = p.add(() => makePromise("A"));
var B = p.add(() => makePromise("B"));
var C = p.add(() => makePromise("C"));
var D = p.add(() => makePromise("D"));
B.after(A);
C.after(A);
C.after(D);
p.execute().then(console.log);
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but your code is using really confusing terminology. `add()` does not take a promise as an argument, it takes a function that produces a promise. Same for the properties and names of the `PromiseAfter` and `Promises` classes. Better call them "tasks".

Answer (score -1):

Some scary posts here

Below `work` is a generic function to produce promised values. Replace `work` with any promise-producing function. `run` encodes the dependency graph -

```js
const work = value =>
  new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 1000, value))

async function run() {
  const [a,d] = await Promise.all([work("A"), work("D")])
  const ctask = work(a + d + "->C")
  const btask = work(a + "->B")
  return Promise.all([ctask, btask])
}

run().then(console.log).catch(console.error)
```

Comment: Not sure what's so scary about the other posts?

Comment: Your dependency graph does not match the one from the question. D and B should be able to run concurrently since they do not depend on each other.